# Is there any pdf reader or editor (free) to highlight in MANY colors? (Not in only one yellow color)

Tags: themes, pdf, colors, document

I'm using Document Viewer, and I can not highlight texts in multiple colors. On Adobe Acrobat Reader I used to highlight texts in many colors,
[image: Windows, Adobe Acrobat Reader]

but now I've changed my OS to UBUNTU, so I need the alternative program to highlight in **multiple** colors.
If you know about that's kind of program, please help me!)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. Okular.
You can add any color you like by going to configure annotations --> add.
[image]

This is how it might look:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also Evince (Document Viewer), the standard PDF viewer of the Ubuntu desktop, allows to change colors of the annotations. Unfortunately, you cannot change the default color of an inserted image: only a yellow annotation is inserted, which then can be changed to another color.

2014, [help.gnome,org](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotation-properties.html.en), and still applicable today:

> The default annotation properties (author, colour, style and icon) can only be changed on a particular note as stated above. So if you want all icons for your notes to be red instead of yellow, you will have to change the default from yellow to red individually on each note. There is no way to save different default settings for annotation properties, at this time.